# What is Namoroka, and should I have it instead of Minefield or Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox

Can someone please clear up what the difference between Namoroka, Minefield, and Firefox 4 is? Which one will eventually "win out," and which one should I have installed?

My 10.10 install came with Namoroka, and it's fast so I like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the firefox wiki:

> After Firefox3.5 ("Shiretoko") is
>   released, the next version of Firefox
>   will be developed under the project
>   name "Namoroka". The Firefox version
>   number will be "3.6" and the Gecko
>   Platform version number will be
>   "1.9.2". The release will be shipped
>   as a minor update to users, replacing
>   Firefox 3.5 ("Shiretoko").
>
> Namoroka is to be an incremental
>   release, building upon the success of
>   Firefox 3.5.

you can get more information [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Namoroka)

Firefox 4 is currently in RC (Release Candidate) mode, meaning its nearing its final launch date. While I'm using it for my day to day browsing its safe to keep your Namoroka install until 4.0 reaches its release date

Minefield was/is the name of the nightly build of FireFox 4. A little snippet about Firefox Minefield:

> WARNING: THIS IS NOT A FINAL VERSION OF FIREFOX. This program is provided without any guarantees of stability and you should back up your profile regularly as there may be bugs that corrupt your data. If that sounds scary, please use the latest version of Firefox.

What this should mean to you, is unless you're willing to deal with breaking changes, constantly, dont run minefield. Its distributed as a public-test release of FireFox so the community can Quality Check the build before it hits a 'near stable' milestone.